# What is the adjective that has the meaning of "no copyright"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

How can I describe a music that does not have copyright?

I found two words on the internet but I'm not sure if they are correct:

**1. Uncopyrighted Music**

**2. Non-copyrighted Music**

Is there a better way to say it?

Thank you very much,

Comment: **uncopyrighted** is used more often. We say "a *piece* of music" or, in this legal context, "a musical work".

Comment: Not an adjective, but "in the public domain"--or "pubic domain" employed attributively or predicatively.

Comment: *Traditional*, *out of copyright*, or *public domain*, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @StoneyB Note, though, that a copyright work can be in the public domain owing to a _copyright exception._ If ever a subject was hard to wrangle, it is this one. Now, when we come to "pubic domain" (sic), that is more easily delineated.
-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is **public domain**.

Note that this refers strictly to works which are not under copyright, either because the copyright term has expired or the author has explicitly waived their right to assert copyright.

Works under "permissive licenses" like Creative Commons or open-source software licenses are *not* "public domain," instead, the author has granted you the consumer the right to use their copyrighted work so long as you adhere to the terms of the license.

Colloquial, catch-all terms for software released under permissive licenses or in the public domain are "open-source software" or "free software." In other fields you would generally use the adjective "free," as in "free music" or "free stock photos." Again, these are colloquial and context-sensitive terms, not legal ones.

More exact terms you might use in a legal context are "music in the public domain," "Creative Commons-licensed music," etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Non copyright" is a possibility

> [Flaming Music - non copyright music](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQlSDYJCCcFNXomqNaKJrVw/about)

As their Youtube channel states

> Non Copyrighted Music For Everyone

another alternative might be

> [CopyrightFree](https://soundcloud.com/cfnetworks) Network on SoundCloud

A more general definition with its origins in [Open Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_model) is

> [Open collaboration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collaboration) is "any system of innovation or production that relies on goal-oriented yet loosely coordinated participants who interact to create a product (or service) of economic value, which they make available to contributors and noncontributors alike.

Wikipedia uses the word

> [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Non-copyright_restrictions)

and points out things in the public domain may still be subject to non-copyright restrictions.